# epplus error on linked picture call from webapi

Tags: azure, gdi+, epplus

I have an issue with EPPLUS linked pictures.

My ExtJs website has a button that calls my Microsoft Azure webapi, and creates and downloads an excel file using EPPLUS.  Everything works fine UNTIL I add a excel linked picture to the template I am using.  (the template is saved on the Azure app service)

The weird thing is it works fine when the app service is run locally, but when I publish to Azure I get the error.

Here is the error...

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(MemoryStream stream)
   at System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture..ctor(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing.GetDrawing(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings.AddDrawings()
   at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings..ctor(ExcelPackage xlPackage, ExcelWorksheet sheet)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray(Boolean save)
   at xxxV003.Models.RepositoryExcel.ExcelSheet(FileInfo xlTemplate, String cName, String calcMethod, String username, Int32 cid)
   at xxxV003.Models.RepositoryExcel.CreatePosSheet(String cName, String _calcMethod, String username, Int32 cid, HttpRequestMessage Request)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Comment: GDI+ is a system-level api.  Not an Azure expert but could it be that your app simply cant get to the api in that kind of Azure service?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean... a bit above my head.  are you saying that azure can't get to the excel features that are on a desktop?  the issue is being caused by the excel linked image

Comment: The issue is it cannot get to the GDI api which epplus uses to generate the image which is part of the host machines OS, or at least that is what the log appears to be indicating.  Again, not an Azure expert but generally with cloud services (PaaS) you do not get a full machine unless you actually pay for a full VM instance.  I would check in with Azure tech support or maybe the Epplus git hub page.  This might help: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/12864567-support-for-gdi